# How to get the particular columns from a SharePoint list view

Tags: list-view, spquery

I am using SPQuery to fetch data (particular columns from the list based on viewID) from SharePoint list.  Here is the code for fetching the data:

```
SPQuery sQuery = new SPQuery();
currentlistview = splist.GetView(new Guid(listViewID));
foreach (string viewField in currentlistview.ViewFields)
{
  SPField spfield = splist.Fields.GetField(viewField);
  SPListColumnValues.Add(spfield);
  sQuery.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='" + viewField + "' />";
}
sQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
sQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
DataTable dt =  splist.GetItems(sQuery).GetDataTable()
```

But I am getting all the columns from the SharePoint list. Could you provide a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Are you looking to get the same results from a view into your datatable? You can send the GetItems the SPView object to do so.

Comment: Did you check whether `currentlistview.ViewFields` is actually returning all the fields in the list?

Comment: kit Menke : I have checked the currentlistview.ViewFields returns only the particular columns(not all the columns) in the list. So what am I doing wrong ? Could you help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The code which you are using data table to store received items. So that, data table will contain whole thing returned, now try something read specific column from the data table.

Try and implement following code:

```
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("siteURL");
    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml =
        @"<View>
            <Query>
              <Where>
                <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='EmpName'/>
                  <Value Type='Text'>XYZ</Value>
                </Eq>
              </Where>
            </Query>
            <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
          </View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(
         listItems,
         items => items
             .Include(
                 item => item["Title"],
                 item => item["EmpName"],
                 item => item["EmpDepart"]));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", listItem["Title"]);
        Console.WriteLine("EmpName: {0}", listItem["EmpName"]);
        Console.WriteLine("EmpDepart: {0}", listItem["EmpDepart"]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST api to get column value from a SharePoint list.
You just need to pass the url as follows.
**url** = YourSiteURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTNAME')/items?$select=ID,Title

```
 $.ajax({
url: url,
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  success: function (data) {
   var dataResults = data.d.results;
   if(dataResults.length > 0){
    for(x = 0; x < dataResults.length; x++){
     columnValue = dataResults[x].ColumnName;
    }
   }
  }
 });
```

For more information about how to use rest api, please click the following link
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/